# Problem with regex for text parsing (similar to textile)

Tags: php, regex, markup, textile

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out a (regexp?) based parser rule for the following problem. I'm developing a text markup parser similar to textile (using PHP), but i don't know how to get the inline formatting rules correct -- and i noticed, that the textile parsers i found are not able to format the following text as i would like to get it formatted:

```
-*deleted* -- text- and -more deleted text-
```

The result I want to have is:

```
<del><strong>deleted</strong> -- text</del> and <del>more deleted text</del>
```

What I do **not** want is:

```
<del><strong>deleted</strong> </del>- text- and <del>more deleted text</del>
```

Any ideas are very appreciated! thanks very much!

**UPDATE**

i think i should have mentioned, that '-' should still be a valid character (hyphen) :) -- for example the following should be possible:

```
-american-football player-
```

expected result:

```
<del>american-football player</del>
```

Comment: Why not use Textile or Markdown in the first place? Saves you time and trouble.

Comment: because, the implementations i found apparently have limitations in formatting. i too dislike several formatting rules -- i need a mixture of textile, markdown and restructured text -- something that behaves 100% how i would like it to behave :-)

Comment: I think you need to employ some artificial intelligence with mind reading capabilities ;) How do you guess to parse `-american-football-player` for example? You need to formulate general, clear and consistent parsing rules in human language or in a collection of examples and only then try to translate them to regexps or whatever.

Comment: @rorick: i think my rules are quite easy for a human to formulate: opening '-' at the beginning of a sentence and/or when there's a whitespace before. closing '-': end of sentence or following whitespace. i don't think that you need special AI for this, however: it might be the case, that my rules would be to complex to achieve with regex, but this was part of my question.

Comment: @harald - Rorick pointed out, correctly, that you're missing a few input/output examples in your question, and showed another edge case. That said, is the latest version I've posted working for you?

Comment: @harald: So `-american-football-player` results in the same string. And what about `-american-football -player-`? Should it be `<del>american-football -player</del>` or `-american-football <del>player</del>` or another string?

Comment: @kobi: looks promising, i'll do some further tests ...

Comment: @rorick: sorry, maybe i misunderstood your first comment. to your question: i would expect it to be <del>american-football -player</del>, because in my opinion this much more makes sense than anything else i can think of. ...

Answer (score 2):

Based of the [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/) library's [parser description](http://github.com/jgarber/redcloth/blob/8f767de26e62e605e23b1f0c7725c911adc645c5/ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_inline.rl#L43), with some modification for double-dash.

```
@
  (?<!\S)               # Start of string, or after space or newline
  -                     # Opening dash
  (                     # Capture group 1
    (?:                 #   : (see note 1)
      [^-\s]+           #   :
      [-\s]+            #   :
    )*?                 #   :
    [^-\s]+?            #   :
  )                     # End
  -                     # Closing dash
  (?![^\s!"\#$%&',\-./:;=?\\^`|~[\]()<])  # (see note 2)
@x
```

- **Note 1:** This should match up to the next dash lazily, while consuming any non-single dashes, and single dashes surrounded by whitespace.
- **Note 2:** Followed by space, punctuation, line break or end of string.

Or compacted:

```
@(?<!\S)-((?:[^-\s]+[-\s]+)*?[^-\s]+?)-(?![^\s!"#$%&',\-./:;=?\\^`|~[\]()<])@
```

A few examples:

```
$regex = '@(?<!\S)-((?:[^-\s]+[-\s]+)*?[^-\s]+?)-(?![^\s!"#$%&\',\-./:;=?\\\^`|~[\]()<])@';
$replacement = '<del>\1</del>';

preg_replace($regex, $replacement, '-*deleted* -- text- and -more deleted text-'), "\n";
preg_replace($regex, $replacement, '-*deleted*--text- and -more deleted text-'), "\n";
preg_replace($regex, $replacement, '-american-football player-'), "\n";
```

Will output:

```
<del>*deleted* -- text</del> and <del>more deleted text</del>
<del>*deleted*</del>-text- and <del>more deleted text</del>
<del>american-football player</del>
```

In the second example, it will match just `-*deleted*-`, since there are no spaces before the `--`. `-text-` will not be matched, because the initial `-` is not preceded by a space.

Answer (score 1):

For a single token, you can simply match:

```
-((?:[^-]|--)*)-
```

and replace with:

```
<del>$1</del>
```

and similarly for `\*((?:[^*]|\*{2,})*)\*` and `<strong>$1</strong>`.

The regex is quite simple: literal `-` in both ends. In the middle, in a capturing group, we allow anything that isn't an hyphen, or two hyphens in a row.

To also allow single dashes in words, as in `objective-c`, this can work, by accepting dashes surrounded by two alphanumeric letters:

```
-((?:[^-]|--|\b-\b)*)-
```

Comment: Ok, for this example it works -- but '-' should be still a valid character in the text. for example "-objective-c-" should become "<del>objective-c</del>".

Comment: @harald - well, you didn't mention you need it :)

Answer (score 1):

The `strong` tag is easy:

```
$string = preg_replace('~[*](.+?)[*]~', '<strong>$1</strong>',  $string);
```

*Working on the others.*

---

*Shameless* hack for the `del` tag:

```
$string = preg_replace('~-(.+?)-~', '<del>$1</del>', $string);
$string = str_replace('<del></del>', '--', $string);
```

Comment: That'd be `str_replace('</del><del>', '--', $string);`. I guess that's the problem with hacks :)

Comment: @Kobi: Oh! Didn't even noticed that! Your solution is way better and the OP should use it. I had a very similar one but couldn't get the non-capturing group to work... I'm out of patience today - been awake for 22 hrs. :P

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
'/-.*?[^-]-\b/'
```

Where the ending hyphen must be at a word boundary and preceded by something that is not a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this warning sign first 
[You can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Perhaps you should try googling for a php html library

Comment: A valid comment would be that you cannot match nested quotes, or in this case `*` and `-`, for example `- aa * bb - cc - bb * aa-`.